# XSLT: Get user's name

Tags: xslt

I have a column whose type is Person or Group.
I'm trying to show the user or group in that column. I have managed to remove special characters using `disable-output-escaping="yes"`.
However, if the column contains a person, the user's login name is being shown, as opposed of his name. For instance, I see this `DOMAIN\jdoe` as opposed to `John Doe`

How can I show the user's name?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do `<xsl:value-of select="@PersonColum.title" />` to retrieve the user's display name.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. However, using title I still see the login name. The only difference is that I don't need to include disable-output-escaping="yes"

Comment: Is the column set to display account name instead of name?

Comment: I just tried this in SharePoint 2016 and it returns nothing.